# How to use a Request class to validate

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-validation

How can I validate a request without the dependency injection?

I need to validate two different thing in the same posting. For example, I need to run a basic validation for an entry, but also I need to validate credit card information, the payment method could change, that's why I don't add the credit card data in the basic entry request.

In my method I have:

```
public method create (EntryRequest $request) {

Validator::make($request->all(), 
[rules] 
}
```

But I already have my rules in a `CreditCardRequest`. How can I apply the rules to that request?

```
Like Validator::make($request->all(), new CreditCardRequest())
```

Comment: The rules is just a simple array that you can store in the model or in a value class for example and use in all of your validators.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do conditional validation in form request classes. So if you only wanted to validated credit card fields if `payment_method` is `card`, then you could do that like this:

```php
class StorePaymentRequest extends FormRequest
{
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'payment_method' => ['required', 'in:card,paypal'],
            // Any other basic rules for the request
        ];
    }

    public function withValidator($validator)
    {
        // Conditionally add validation for card fields if payment method is card
        $cardFields = ['card_number', 'expiry_date', 'cvc'];

        $validator->sometimes($cardFields, 'required', function ($input) {
            return $input->payment_method == 'card';
        });
    }
}
```

Documentation: https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#conditionally-adding-rules

Answer (score 1):

I believe you mean like this!
You include your own StoreRequest File, and use it to validate like so.

```
use App\Http\Requests\CreditCardRequest;

public function store(CreditCardRequest $request)
{    
    $data = $request->validated();
}
```